# Algebraic Dimension of function space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cardinals

Let $F$ be a field and $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Assume (by AC) that $F^X$ has a base, i.e. there exists a cardinal $\lambda$ so that
$$ F^\kappa := \prod_{i \in \kappa} F \cong \bigoplus_{i \in \lambda} F =: F^{(\lambda)} .$$
I know that $\lambda$ is uniquely determined. Is there a general formula to derive $\lambda$ from $\kappa$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49551/dimension-of-infinite-product-of-vector-spaces